# Neo4j and Cypher: Reversing Only One Arrow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have three nodes in my Neo4j graph, with directed relationships like this: `(a)<--(b)-->(c)`. Furthermore, assume that `(b)` does NOT have the property `visit_type_name`, whereas both `(a)` and `(c)` do. Now what I would like to do is reverse ***only one*** of these arrows. For the moment, it does not matter which one, although being able to specify conditions, involving properties, on which one to reverse would be nice. I tried the following:

```
MATCH(x)-[r]->(y)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(()-->(x))
    AND NOT EXISTS(x.visit_type_name)
DELETE r
MERGE(y)-->(x)
```

My thought was that after this code reversed, say, the arrow `(a)<--(b)` to `(a)-->(b)`, then `(b)` would no longer be parent-less, and the `MATCH` would not continue on and do the same thing with the `(b)-->(c)` link. Unfortunately, Cypher does continue and reverse both arrows, which is not what I want. So then I tried this, thinking that I needed to change the granularity of the Cypher match:

```
MATCH(y)
WITH y
MATCH(x)-[r]->(y)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(()-->(x))
    AND NOT EXISTS(x.visit_type_name)
DELETE r
MERGE(y)-->(x)
```

Unfortunately, this does the same thing as before.

> How can I reverse only one arrow in this situation?

Is there a way to finalize the first arrow reversal transaction before moving on?

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a method of doing this. Each node has a unique numerical `id` which I can leverage as follows:

```
MATCH(x)-->(y)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(()-->(x))
    AND NOT EXISTS(x.visit_type_name)
WITH MIN(y.id) AS min_y_id, x
MATCH(x)-[r]->(min_y)
WHERE min_y.id = min_y_id
DELETE r
MERGE(min_y)-->(x)
```

This essentially picks out the minimum `id` and only reverses the arrow for the corresponding node.